# Google AdMob: strange error + CPU usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I want to tell you about strange problem with Google Ad Mob SDK in my iOS app. Sometimes, when GADInterstitial is created, the following message spams to console (app running in debug mode):

> void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:
>   decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)
>   failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode:
>   kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

I added a symbolic breakpoint on `webView: decidePolicyForNavigationAction: request: frame: decisionListener:` and figured out, that error appears on **Thread 1, queue: com.google.admob.sdk-core-controller**.

The error messages are often accomplished by high CPU usage (65% - 75%). User interface responds slower and slower until the app is killed.

iOS vesions: 7.1, 8 beta 4.

I probably must report this to google developers, but I'll also leave it here.

Comment: looks like I have the same issue here. Did you get this solved? Thanks

Comment: Nope. AdMob SDK was updated since then I asked the question, however I'm still getting strange log messages while app is running. The app stopped to be constantly killed, at least.